# custom sort method from scratch that takes a comparator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have been tasked to write a completely custom sort method (cant use `Array.sort()`) that takes a comparator and sorts a list based on said comparator.

```js
const people = [
  {name: 'Bill', age: 30, likes: 'food'},
  {name: 'Andrew', age: 17, likes: 'games'},
  {name: 'Kyle', age: 59, likes: 'cats'},
]

function sortArr(comparator, array) {
  // code goes here
}

function exampleComparator(int1, int2) {
  if (int1 > int2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

An example of a comparator I have to build is something that sorts by name and another one that sorts by age.

I would call the function like this: `sortArr(ageComparator, people)` which would then sort the array by the age of the people.

However, I am struggling really hard for the sort array. I initially thought I could use the built in array sort method but my professor said that is not allowed. I don't know how to approach the `sortArr` function to utilize a comparator that is passed in which returns a boolean value and then sorts based on that value.

I can easily implement an insertion sort of types but then I get stuck at how to utilize the comparator.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Is there a better sort algorithm that will make this process easier?

Thank you.

Comment: Just write your insertion sort algorithm and replace every `arr[i] <= arr[j]` with `comparator(arr[i], arr[j])`

Answer (score 2):

Taking a closer look at the example comparator

```
function exampleComparator(int1, int2) {
  if (int1 > int2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

One can notice that the main goal is have a sorting algorithm where a comparator is passed to evaluate `int1` and `int2` (or `object1` vs `object2` in a general sense). So let's take for example the bubble sort algorithm:

```
function sortArr(inputArr) {
  let len = inputArr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
      if (inputArr[j] > inputArr[j + 1]) { // this is where the comparison happens
        let tmp = inputArr[j];
        inputArr[j] = inputArr[j + 1];
        inputArr[j + 1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So we need to pass our custom comparator and let it do the comparison e.g. (sorting by age ascending)

```js
const people = [{
    name: 'Bill',
    age: 30,
    likes: 'food'
  },
  {
    name: 'Andrew',
    age: 17,
    likes: 'games'
  },
  {
    name: 'Kyle',
    age: 59,
    likes: 'cats'
  },
]

function ageComparator(a, b) {
  if (a.age > b.age) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function sortArr(comparator, inputArr) {
  let len = inputArr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
      if (comparator(inputArr[j], inputArr[j + 1])) {
        let tmp = inputArr[j];
        inputArr[j] = inputArr[j + 1];
        inputArr[j + 1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
}

sortArr(ageComparator, people)
console.log(people)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Been pulling my hair out for the past 2 days trying to understand and solve this problem. Im currently eating dinner but will dive into your code afterwards. Appreciate the response!